# Match value in dataframe to other occurences in other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like the one below:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('x', 'y', 'z', 't', 'm'), b = c('x', 'x', 'y', NA, 'm'))

> df
  a    b
1 x    x
2 y    x
3 z    y
4 t <NA>
5 m    m
```

Now, for every value in both column 'a' and 'b' I want to see if it exists in any other row in both 'a' and 'b' and return a match. So, for row 1 I want to see if 'x' or 'y' exists in row 2:5 in either column a or b and then return 'TRUE'.

My desired result would then be:

```
> df$match = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
> df
  a    b match
1 x    x  TRUE
2 y    x  TRUE
3 z    y  TRUE
4 t <NA> FALSE
5 m    m FALSE
```

Can't seem to figure out a way to do this. I've been trying to use dplyr:

```
df %>%
  mutate(match = a %in% b | a %in% a | b %in% b | b %in% a)
```

but this just returns everything as TRUE. Furthermore if b is NA, then it will match to any other NA value aswell which is not intended.

Using rowwise operations also doesn't work, this just checks the value within the row.

Comment: If one exists and the other doesn't it will return TRUE?

Comment: If you mean row 3 in the desired result, it should return TRUE because the 'y'  in column 'b' exists in row 2 in column 'a'. Otherwise I might not understand your question correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach to your problem using `purrr::imap`:

- Since I used formula shortcut to define my function `.x` argument refers to value and `.y` argument refers to the position/name
- I first transpose your data set (thought that way might be easier) then iterate over each column and checked whether any element can be found in other columns
- For the purpose of checking the presence of values I used `.y` argument to remove the corresponding index of each column from the original data set as for example first column elements in the transposed data set is exactly the same as the values in the first row of the original data set

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique") %>%
  imap_lgl(~ any(unlist(.x) %in% unlist(df[-as.integer(gsub("\\.{3}(\\d)", "\\1", .y)), ]))) %>%
  unlist() -> df$match

  a    b match
1 x    x  TRUE
2 y    x  TRUE
3 z    y  TRUE
4 t <NA> FALSE
5 m    m FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the option with `igraph` like below

```
library(igraph)

transform(
  merge(
    df,
    stack(membership(components(graph_from_data_frame(replace(df, is.na(df), "NA"))))),
    by.x = "a", by.y = "ind"
  ),
  Match = ave(values, values, FUN = length) > 1
)
```

which gives you

```
  a    b values Match
1 m    m      3 FALSE
2 t <NA>      2 FALSE
3 x    x      1  TRUE
4 y    x      1  TRUE
5 z    y      1  TRUE
```

---

Or we can use `dplyr` like below (sorry that my knowledge is very limited, and there must be better solution than mine)

```
df %>%
  left_join(df %>%
    mutate(b = fcoalesce(b, a)) %>%
    graph_from_data_frame() %>%
    components() %>%
    membership() %>%
    stack(),
  by = c("a" = "ind")
  ) %>%
  group_by(values) %>%
  mutate(Match = n() > 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-values)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  a     b     Match
  <chr> <chr> <lgl>
1 x     x     TRUE
2 y     x     TRUE
3 z     y     TRUE
4 t     NA    FALSE
5 m     m     FALSE
```

Comment: You are being so humble this is an excellent solution.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Thank you. Your solution looks much shorter. Cool!

Comment: Yous are too! I wish I had known `igprah` :D

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I (personally) think `igraph` is easier than `dplyr` :P I believe you will master it soon.

Comment: I forgot a lot about graph theory, So I think I have to review it beforehand. Thanks I am going to ask you many question about `igraph`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will also do.  Since `NA %in% c(NA, 'c')` results in TRUE we can add further conditions to check whether current value is non-NA

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c('x', 'y', 'z', 't', 'm'), b = c('x', 'x', 'y', NA, 'm'))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(xx = map_lgl(row_number(), ~ (a[.x] %in% c(a[-.x], b[-.x]) | b[.x] %in% c(a[-.x], b[-.x])) & !is.na(a[.x]) & !is.na(b[.x]) ))

#>   a    b    xx
#> 1 x    x  TRUE
#> 2 y    x  TRUE
#> 3 z    y  TRUE
#> 4 t <NA> FALSE
#> 5 m    m FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>